# Want to show the results of a page in another page?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I've created a windows phone 7 application using Isolated Storage. In this application i've used a button named as btnRead, a textblock named as txtRead and a text box named as txtWrite. If i write something to the textbox(txtWrite) and clicked on the button(btnRead). Then the textblock(txtRead) shows or saves whatever i write on textbox(All these are created in a single MainPage.xaml). Now I have created another page1.xaml and created a textblock named as txtShow. But I want the textblock(txtShow) to show all the things that i write on textbox which is in MainPage.xaml. I have also uploaded my project- https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=ea5aaefa4ad2307a&resid=EA5AAEFA4AD2307A!133&parid=EA5AAEFA4AD2307A!109

Below is MainPage.xaml.cs source that i have used -:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        IsolatedStorageFile myStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        myStore.CreateDirectory("Bookmark");

        using (var isoFileStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("Bookmark\\myFile.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, myStore))
        {
            //Write the data
            using (var isoFileWriter = new StreamWriter(isoFileStream))
            {
                isoFileWriter.WriteLine(txtWrite.Text);
            }
        }

        try
        {
            // Specify the file path and options.
            using (var isoFileStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("Bookmark\\myFile.txt", FileMode.Open, myStore))
            {
                // Read the data.
                using (var isoFileReader = new StreamReader(isoFileStream))
                {
                    txtRead.Text = isoFileReader.ReadLine();
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            // Handle the case when the user attempts to click the Read button first.
            txtRead.Text = "Need to create directory and the file first.";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are displaying the text from the TextBox in a TextBlock in the same page, it would be easier to do that through binding

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtWrite"/>
<TextBlock  Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=txtWrite}"/>
```

To put this information into the next page you could put it into the NavigationContext to pass to the next page

```
    // Navigate to Page1 FROM MainPage 
    // This can be done in a button click event
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page1.xaml?text=" + txtWrite.Text, UriKind.Relative));

// Override OnNavigatedTo in Page1.xaml.cs
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    string text;
    NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("text", out text);
    txtRead.Text = text;
}
```

If you like using IsoStorage, you could do the read like you are doing above in the OnNavigatedTo method.

Comment: Then add it to a ListBox: listBox.Items.Add(text);