# Need to show the contents of one page in another page in a listbox?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I want to create a windows phone 7 application using Isolated Storage. I have created two pages named as MainPage.xaml and Page1.xaml. In MainPage.xaml, i've created a button named as button1 and a textBox named as textBox1. In Page1.xaml, i've created a listbox named as listBox1. If i write something into the textBox1 and when i clicked on button1 (which is in MainPage.xaml), i need the listBox1 to show all the contents, whatever i write into the textBox1 and also i need to save the contents which is in listBox1 to Isolated Storage. Can anyone help with this???...I've researched so many places regarding this. Thanks in advance for your hard work!!!

Comment: Besides ListBox instead of TextBox, how is this different from your post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10541451/want-to-show-the-results-of-a-page-in-another-page

Answer (score 0):

In Mainpage.xaml

Private void button1_click()

{

```
 string message = textbox1.text;

 NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(String.format("/Page1.xaml?value1 = {0}",message), UriKind.Relative));}
```

In Page1.Xaml

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)

{

```
 base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

 string newparameter = "";

 this.NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("value1", out newparameter);

 listbox1.items.add(newparameter.ToString());}
```

then get the newparameter string and save it in isostore. Any help further ask me.

Comment: There is an error - NullReferenceException was unhandled      highlighting----> listbox1.items.add(newparameter.ToString());}
Need help SENTHIL KUMAR....

Answer (score 0):

In MainPage.xaml.cs,you can write like:

```
Private void button1_click()
{
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page1.xaml?content="+textBox1.Text,UriKind.Relative));
}
```

In the Page1.xaml.cs you can write like this:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.IsolatedStorage;

namespace PhoneApp1
{
public partial class Page1 : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public static List<string> list = new List<string>();
    public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        listBox1.ItemsSource = list;
        IsolatedStorageFile storge = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("/list.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, storge));
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            writer.WriteLine(list[i]);
        }   
        writer.Close();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("content"))
        {
            list.Add(NavigationContext.QueryString["content"]);
        }
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    }
}
}
```